# How to "Spawn" a Wall album in a new page

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-wall, koala

I am trying to post pictures to customers' pages. There may or may not be a "Wall Photos" album in the page.

In scenarios where there is not a pre-existing "Wall Photos" album how would I create / request the creation of a wall photo album?

I am using Koala and I can create albums, but I cannot create albums with type = "wall".

here is the code I am using to create / find albums:

```
def get_photo_album(facebook_id)

  # Looking for a pre-existing WALL PHOTO album
  p "============= Getting Wall Photos album for fbid #{facebook_id}"
  album = get_album facebook_id, 'Wall Photos'

  unless album
    p ' ======= Album FAIL 1 - getting Photos '
    album = get_album facebook_id, FALLBACK_ALBUM_NAME
    unless album
      p ' ========== Album FAIL 2 - MAKING Phtoos '
      @graph_client.put_object facebook_id, 'albums', 'name' => FALLBACK_ALBUM_NAME

      sleep 3 # wait 3 seconds to let facebook make and fiddle with new album

      album = get_album facebook_id, FALLBACK_ALBUM_NAME
      unless album
        p ' ##################### UTTER ALBUM FAIL '
        raise "Cannot use alternative photo album"
      end
    end
  end

  if album && album.length > 0
    album
  else
    # ensure that there is an album.
    raise "Cannot use alternative photo album"
  end
end

def get_album(facebook_id, name)

  params = {'name' => name};

  albums = @graph_client.get_connections(facebook_id, "albums", params)

  p "Found #{albums ? albums.length : 0} albums named #{name} for fbid #{facebook_id}"
  albums = albums.reject do |a|
    a['name'] != name
  end
  p "Found #{albums ? albums.length : 0} albums named #{name} for fbid #{facebook_id} AFTER filtering for name"
  pp albums

  albums.length >0 ? albums[0] : nil
end
```

end

And here is the Koala code I am using to put the picture itself

```
def put_image(facebook_id, params)
  params = sanitize_params(params)
  params = encode_necessary_params(params)


  picture = URI.decode(params['picture'])


  photo_album = get_photo_album(facebook_id)
  photo_album_id = photo_album['id']

  params = params.reject do |key, value|
    key == 'metadata_type'
  end

  p ' -------------------------------------- PUT PICTURE ----------------------------'
  p "fbid:#{facebook_id}, message: #{params['message']}, picture: #{picture}"
  p ' -------------------------------------- PUT PICTURE ----------------------------'

  out = @graph_client.put_picture picture, {:message => params['message']}, photo_album_id
  Statsd.increment("posts")
  out
rescue Exception => ex


  handle_error(ex)

end
```

I have tried several variations including:

- putting 'type' => 'wall' in the @graph_client.put_object parameters: doesn't post the image at all
- creating an album named 'Wall Photos' - the album appears, but the posts don't look like wall posts.

To be clear: **The ultimate goal is for all posts to this album to have "big" previews - full column width, not tiled 1" previews. **

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do isn't going to be possible - the Wall Photos album is a special album which is generated from photos posted to feed, and there is no API available to post photos that way - if you post to /photos they go into an album specifically for the app.

However, all is not lost. If you're willing to embrace newer functionality, you'll both be able to meet your goal of having large photos in feed whilst also achieving greater viral potential for your app. The answer is Open Graph Actions. Specifically [User Generated Photos in Open Graph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/usergeneratedphotos/)

The process for this is relatively simple:

1. Create an Open Graph action and object for your app (do this from the Developer App Dashboard for that particular app), this can be anything depending on what your app does, but, for example, Instagram uses 'took' as their OG action and 'a photo' as their OG object. This means that posts from that app look like "Matthew took a photo with Instagram" and show the photo below. Which action you want to use is up to you.
2. Request `publish_actions` permission from your app users, if you haven't been already.
3. Make API calls to:

`https://graph.facebook.com/me/YOURAPPNAMESPACE:YOURACTION?
  YOUROBJECTTYPE=URLWHEREYOUROGOBJECTISLOCATED&
  image[0][url]=URLOFPHOTOYOUWANTTOADD&
  image[0][user_generated]=true`

You'll also need to sign this API call with the access token for that user, or I believe, if you have publish_actions for that user, you can make the above call to /USERID instead of /me and use your app's access token and it will work.

As you can see from [the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/usergeneratedphotos/) this will give you the full sized photo that you're after and having it be created by an Open Graph action allows for a whole host of extra virality if you incorporate extras such as OG action links, authenticated referrals etc.